# jsp jar Failed to load

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, jsp-tags

In the `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT` I have the following structure =>

```
META-INF  teiExample.jsp  WEB-INF

./META-INF:
context.xml

./WEB-INF:
exampleTags.tld  lib  web.xml

./WEB-INF/lib:
example.jar
```

Content of the example.jar =>

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
classes/utilities/arrayExtraInfo.class
classes/utilities/createArrayTag.class
exampleTags.tld
```

teiExample.jsp =>

```
<%@ taglib prefix="example" uri="exampleURI" %>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Welcome and time example</title>
</head>

<body>

<example:createArray name="theArray" />
We are now using a JAR file<BR />
The array has <%= theArray.length %> items.<BR />

</body>
</html>
```

exampleTags.tld =>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">
<taglib>
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <jsp-version>1.2</jsp-version>
    <short-name>ExampleTags</short-name>
    <uri>exampleURI</uri>
    <description>A set of example tag handlers.</description>

    <tag>
        <name>createArray</name>
        <tag-class>utilities.createArrayTag</tag-class>
        <tei-class>utilities.arrayExtraInfo</tei-class>
        <attribute>
            <name>name</name>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

web.xml =>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>exampleTags</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/exampleTags.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</web-app>
```

But all I get is =>

```
    HTTP Status 500 - 

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagExtraInfo class: utilities.arrayExtraInfo
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:409)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:281)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.createTagInfo(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:419)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.parseTLD(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:250)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:163)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:382)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:445)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:170)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:332)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:589)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: utilities.arrayExtraInfo
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1484)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.createTagInfo(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:416)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.parseTLD(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:250)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:163)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:382)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:445)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:170)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:332)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:589)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.24 logs.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.24
```

Why please? And, do I need `web.xml` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagExtraInfo class: utilities.arrayExtraInfo

This just means that under the covers

```
TagExtraInfo tag = (TagExtraInfo) Class.forName("utilities.arrayExtraInfo").newInstance();
```

has failed.

I.e. either the class is not present in the classpath or does not have a default no-arg constructor. The real root cause should however be present in the stacktrace. Read a bit further in the stacktrace, the bottommost part is the real root cause of the problem.

In your case class name is incorrect. As you've structured your JAR, the class name should be `classes.utilities.arrayExtraInfo` or you should get rid of the `/classes` folder in the JAR.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: please read the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Classnames ought to start with uppercase.

Comment: I have edited the original post (just add the full error report)

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` just means that the class is missing in the classpath or that the class name is incorrect. See answer update.

Comment: I have now `<tag-class>classes.utilities.createArrayTag</tag-class>` and error : `javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: classes/utilities/arrayExtraInfo (wrong name: utilities/arrayExtraInfo)`

Comment: The class itself has the `package utilities;`. So you **actually** need to get rid of `/classes` folder :)

Comment: it works, thank you for your time. So all I need here is 3 things: teiExample.jsp, example.jar and exampleTags.tld. What about web.xml, when do I need that? Thanks

Comment: Use it to declare webapp-specific init params, servlets, listeners and/or filters.